# how make elements of a list lower case?

Tags: pyspark

I have a df tthat one of the columns is a set of words. How I can make them lower case in the efficient way?
The df has many column but the column that I am trying to make it lower case is like this:

```
B
['Summer','Air Bus','Got']
['Parmin','Home']
```

Note:

In pandas I do `df['B'].str.lower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a column that is an array of strings.

To lower the string, you can use `lower` function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


data = [
    {"B": ["Summer", "Air Bus", "Got"]},
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.withColumn("result", F.expr("transform(B, x -> lower(x))"))
```

Result:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+                                 
|B                     |result                |
+----------------------+----------------------+
|[Summer, Air Bus, Got]|[summer, air bus, got]|
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: for some reason it takes too much time

Comment: @user15649753 Not sure where you are running it and how much data you have. If your data is huge, I suspect it could be slow.

Comment: How to pass the  dynamic column name  inside the transform function?

Comment: @merkle, you can try this: `m = "B"; df = df.withColumn("result", F.transform(F.col(m),lambda x: F.lower(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on @vladsiv's answer, which tries to answer a question in the comments about passing a dynamic column name.

```
# set column name
m = "B"

# use F.tranform directly, rather than in a F.expr
df = df.withColumn("result", F.transform(F.col(m), lambda x:F.lower(x)))
```